# Is gitosis or gitolite necessary to push changes via HTTP/HTTPS to remote git repository?

Tags: git, authentication, https, apache-http-server, gitolite

I have an apache2 server running a virtual host with HTTPS and basic authentication enabled.  The virtual host serves [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) repositories via [gitweb](http://repo.or.cz/w/alt-git.git?a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/README) script. Authenticated users pull repositories from virtual host.

I don't need fine access control since I am using basic authentication mechanism. Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is [gitweb](http://repo.or.cz/w/alt-git.git?a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/README) the only thing I need to pull AND push changes with this setup?
2. If not enough, do I need gitolite or gitosis to push changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gitweb is only a vizualization mechanism. You don't need it to pull/push.
A simple Apache server calling the [`git-http-backend` mechanism](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) is enough.

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (please, no gitosis: it is obsolete) is an **authorization** mechanism, also not needed to push/pull (unless you want to restrict access to a group of users).

More details in:

- [Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix)
- My presentation I gave to [CodeKen London 2011](http://london2011.codeken.com/dvcs-git-daniel-chaffiol/): "[Introducing Git in big corporation](http://www.slideshare.net/dchaffiol/dvcs-in-big-corporation)"

Comment: -To push/pull (via Smart HTTP protocol), only git-http-backend is required.
-To view/restrict/enable user access; gitweb or gitolite is required.

Am I right ?

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti: to view, just gitweb is required. Gitolite is only there to intercept any git command and accept or deny said command based on the user requiring access to a repo through that command. You can interface gitweb with Gitolite if you want your visualization interface to benefit from the authorization layer: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ggshb.html

Comment: In my setup, authorization layer is managed by Apache's Basic Authentication mechanism.

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti: nope: Apache's Basic Authentication, as its name suggests, is for **authentication**, NOT (I repeat *not*) authorization. Please read: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html